# Reference database for recreational math problems and math puzzles?

Tags: reference-request, education

Recreational math books contain duplicates for problems.

I think, classical examples are `SEND + MORE = MONEY` and Zebra puzzles. (Though I can't point exact books which include those, I only know they are popular)

Is there a community database that collects these common math problems, assigns IDs and tracks history of both creation and usage across literature?

Comment: I believe it is safe to say that the answer is "no".

Comment: No but there ought to be. Maybe in this era of wikis and MathJax it's possible for such to be created. Well volunteered, that man.